# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource asp.net

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, iis-7.5, webmethod, preflight

I am facing problem with Cross Domain Ajax call. When I call a asp.net WebMethod through Ajax Call I got warning : Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed

Here is complete code

Server Code :

```
 using System;
 using Customers.BLL;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
 using System.Web.Services;
 using System.Web.Http.Cors;
  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
 public partial class API_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
   static string ApplicationPath = "";
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {       
   }
   [WebMethod]

   public static string ValidateUser(string UserName)
   {
    string strJson = "";
    var User = Members.GetCustMaster(UserName);
    if (User != null)
    {
        User.BankName = ApplicationPath + (User.BankName.ToString() != "" ? "Images/Photos/" + User.BankName : "images/avatar.png");
        strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(User);
    }
    else
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Failure failure = new Failure();
        strJson = json.Serialize(failure);
    }

    return strJson;
}


  }
  [Serializable]
  public class Failure
  {
         public bool Status { get { return false; } }
         public string Result { get { return "Record Not found"; } }
     }
```

I have added Headers in Web.config

`<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Token" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
 </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>`

---

Thisis how I am trying to call this webmethod

```
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script >function GetJSon() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.UserName = $("#txt").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://someurl.net/webservices/default.aspx/ValidateUser",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),

        success: function (msg) {
            console.log();
            alert(msg.d)
            $("#test").html(msg.d)
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log();
        }
    });
}</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="demo" id="txt" />
    <input type="button" onclick="GetJSon()" value="jSon" />

    Response : <div id="test">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob4X3.png)